# Reverse a List by Swap Ends

Tags: python, list, reverse

I am trying to reverse a list's order by finding three bugs in this function. This function is supposed to reverse the first and last elements of a list, the second and second to last elements, and so on. I believe I found two, but am having trouble fixing the line of `list[j] = y`.

```
def reverse(list):
    """Reverses elements of a list."""
    for i in range(len(list)):
        j = len(list) - i
        x = list[i]
        y = list[j-1]
        list[i] = x
        list[j] = y 

l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
reverse(l)
print(l)
```

Comment: Do you understand the code? Try to see which two elements are you swapping... then it will be kind of obvious. Also note how many times you are swapping each element (watching old Laurel and Hardy comedies might help find this one).

Comment: What's wrong with `mylist[::-1]`?

Comment: @Evert: I assume it is debugging homework. The point is not to write list reversal, but to find erroneous logic.

Comment: Probably so, yes; given that OP struggles with the code, it seems like a useful exercise. Sorry, just had to point out the obvious.

Comment: Sidenote: the Python idiom for swapping two elements tends to be `x, y = y, x`. That may or may not be applicable here (it's perhaps a shortcut not intended to be taken).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a couple problems.  Your first problem is that you use `list[j] = y` instead of `list[j-1] = x`.  You defined `y` correctly with `j-1`, but you should be changing `list[j-1]` to the other one, `x`.  Another problem is that you are going from the beginning of the list all the way to the end.  Once you get to more than half way through the list, you are undoing your work.  You also don't need to use `len(list)-i` because you can just use `-i`.  Here is the updated code:

```
def reverse(seq):
    """Reverses elements of a list."""
    for i in range(len(seq)//2):
        x = seq[i]
        y = seq[-i-1]
        seq[i] = y
        seq[-i-1] = x

l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
reverse(l)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

You don't even need to define `x` and `y`.  Instead, do this:

```
def reverse(seq):
    """Reverses elements of a list."""
    for i in range(len(list)//2):
        seq[i], seq[-i-1] = seq[-i-1], seq[i]
```

I also changed your naming.  There's probably a better name than `seq`, but `list` is unacceptable because it conflicts with the built-in type.

Comment: don't use list, it is a built-in.

Comment: @NamitSingal: You're absolutely right.  I forgot to change that, but it's changed now.

Comment: @NamitSingal: Pedantic: A built-in, but not a keyword. If it were a keyword, you _couldn't_ use it.

Answer (score 0):

Homework I suspect...

But - we all need a break from homework.  By looping over the whole list you're reversing it twice.

```
def reverse(list):
    """Reverses elements of a list."""
    for i in range(len(list)/2):
        j = i + 1
        x = list[i]
        y = list[-j]
        list[-j] = x
        list[i] = y

l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
l=reverse(l)
print(l)
```

resulting in

```
['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
l=l[::-1]
print(l)
```

Why you want to complicate this simple construction? Or if you don't wanna do this on that way, try to use:

```
l.reverse()
```

function. Python has a lot of functions ready to use.

Comment: Read other comments. `l.reverse()` is a correct answer to a different question. Nobody writes code and knows how many errors it's supposed to have; it has to be an assignment.